# How do I automate the exporting of a result set from an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a View in an SQL Server 2008 database which I need to be exported into a CSV file automatically at the beginning of each month. As I understand, two procedures are needed:

1. The SQL script to automate the export
2. Schedule this task in SQL or Windows

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a job within the SQL server management studio to handle the whole thing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/7d2280cf-3b33-46f7-ba82-4131e8a841c0